# fetchOffset is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Давно смотрю на эту вот [ракету](https://codepen.io/anhnhim/pen/oLwvaQ) с необычным подъемом вверх. Но, смущают некоторые ошибки в консоли, которые появляются при включении режима адаптивного дизайна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем ошибка повторяется при скролле. Если с `TypeError: scrolltoprocketmeluncur.style is undefined` все в общем-то понятно, то, вот справится с `fetchOffset is not defined` не удается.

Сам скрипт целиком:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop()<50){
        jQuery('#rocketmeluncur').slideUp(500);
    }else{
        jQuery('#rocketmeluncur').slideDown(500);
    }
    var ftrocketmeluncur = jQuery("#ft")[0] ? jQuery("#ft")[0] : jQuery(document.body)[0];
    var scrolltoprocketmeluncur = $('rocketmeluncur');
var viewPortHeightrocketmeluncur = parseInt(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
var scrollHeightrocketmeluncur = parseInt(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top);
var basewrocketmeluncur = parseInt(ftrocketmeluncur.clientWidth);
var swrocketmeluncur = scrolltoprocketmeluncur.clientWidth;
if (basewrocketmeluncur < 1000) {
var leftrocketmeluncur = parseInt(fetchOffset(ftrocketmeluncur)['left']);
leftrocketmeluncur = leftrocketmeluncur < swrocketmeluncur ? leftrocketmeluncur * 2 - swrocketmeluncur : leftrocketmeluncur;
scrolltoprocketmeluncur.style.left = ( basewrocketmeluncur + leftrocketmeluncur ) + 'px';
} else {
scrolltoprocketmeluncur.style.left = 'auto';
scrolltoprocketmeluncur.style.right = '10px';
}
})

jQuery('#rocketmeluncur').click(function(){
    jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: '0px',display:'none'},{
            duration: 600,  
            easing: 'linear'
        });

    var self = this;
    this.className += ' '+"launchrocket";
    setTimeout(function(){
      self.className = 'showrocket';
    },800)
});
```

Если кто-то даст какие-то рекомендации, буду премного благодарен.

Comment: кто-то забыл объявить функцию `fetchOffset`

Answer (score 2):

В общем, поковырял немного код и все ошибки поправил.

По факту, заменил 2 участка:

- `var leftrocketmeluncur = parseInt(ftrocketmeluncur.offsetLeft);` - использовал `.offsetLeft` для получения расстояния до объекта в левом углу.
- `scrolltoprocketmeluncur.css('left', (basewrocketmeluncur + leftrocketmeluncur + "px"));
  } else {
  scrolltoprocketmeluncur.css('left', 'auto');
  scrolltoprocketmeluncur.css('right', '10px');` - задаем стили при помощи jQuery

Если кому нужно будет, вот код целиком:

```
//ROCKET TO TOP
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 50) {
        jQuery('#rocketmeluncur').slideUp(500);
    } else {
        jQuery('#rocketmeluncur').slideDown(500);
    }
    var ftrocketmeluncur = jQuery("#ft")[0] ? jQuery("#ft")[0] : jQuery(document.body)[0];
    var scrolltoprocketmeluncur = $('rocketmeluncur');
    var viewPortHeightrocketmeluncur = parseInt(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    var scrollHeightrocketmeluncur = parseInt(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    var basewrocketmeluncur = parseInt(ftrocketmeluncur.clientWidth);
    var swrocketmeluncur = scrolltoprocketmeluncur.clientWidth;
    if (basewrocketmeluncur < 1000) {
        var leftrocketmeluncur = parseInt(ftrocketmeluncur.offsetLeft);
        leftrocketmeluncur = leftrocketmeluncur < swrocketmeluncur ? leftrocketmeluncur * 2 - swrocketmeluncur : leftrocketmeluncur;
        scrolltoprocketmeluncur.css('left', (basewrocketmeluncur + leftrocketmeluncur + "px"));
    } else {
        scrolltoprocketmeluncur.css('left', 'auto');
        scrolltoprocketmeluncur.css('right', '10px');
    }
});

jQuery('#rocketmeluncur').click(function() {
    jQuery("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: '0px',
        display: 'none'
    }, {
        duration: 600,
        easing: 'linear'
    });

    var self = this;
    this.className += ' ' + "launchrocket";
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.className = 'showrocket';
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: добавь описание что именно и как поправил

Comment: @Grundy добавил